# .Net UI and Java Middle Ware

Tags: c#, java, .net

Hi We are in process of building new application which will have .Net UI and Java Middle Ware (Services) what. As I am fairly new to Java i would like to explore my options in terms of what are good practices so that .net uis can talk to java middle tiers. Java middle tier will eventually call to database...

Thanks

Comment: Why not drop the terms UI and database from your question completely? The real question here seems to be, what kind of Java service is compatible with / accessible from a .NET application? I suppose it comes down to protocols.

Comment: Not sure if JNI would help you?

Comment: stakx; I would agree it boils down to Protocols at lowest level. But I would like to reuse existing infrastructure if there are any...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your java middle ware with some sort of service that WCF can communicate with and you should be good to go

Here is a simple example
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bursteg/archive/2008/07/19/how-to-call-a-java-ee-web-service-from-a-net-client.aspx

Comment: Thanks for suggestion; Will I be able to pass complex object from C# to Java web service...I am basically looking for more comprehensive example which I can use in in real world application... Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In addition to designing something that WCF understands, you might consider designing a ReSTful service using standard HTTP semantics.

For the Java side, you can use:

- [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or
- [RESTlet](http://www.restlet.org/)

On the consumer side in .NET, you can use:

- [RestSharp](https://www.github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) or
- [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Any client that can send an HTTP request, REST or SOAP, can communicate with an HTTP listener or service, regardless of which language each one is implemented in.  That's why HTTP based services have been such a winner, beating out Corba, RMI, COM, etc.

Simple and open win.

Comment: I understand this; but if there are any existing infra it will help me to get upto speed quickly... Thanks